# Can the Web Audio API audioctx.destination AudioNode be a virtual audio device?

Tags: core-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

We want to receive the audio tracks from our media and send them to a virtual audio device like S Soundflower, Loopback, Black hole, etc. Is it possible for the .destination to be set on creation of the context, or at another time, to be the virtual device? It seems like the architecture allows for .destination to support this use case. Also there was a later development "setSinkID" is that what will work for this use case?